# How to use the output of an upstream task to drive the result of requires()?

Tags: luigi

In Luigi, I have a task where I want to dynamically generate a list of dependencies based on the output from another upstream task. For example:

```py
class TaskA:
  param = IntParameter()

class TaskB:
  def main(self):
    pass
  def output(self):
    return [1,2,3,4]

class TaskC:
  def requires(self):
    return [TaskB()] + [TaskA(param=p) for p in TaskB().output()]
```

In summary, I am creating a set of TaskA dependencies in TaskC, based on the output from TaskB.

I have tried a few things, but it seems that Luigi gets confused because TaskB really needs to run before TaskC can return its list of dependencies. But obviously Luigi cannot run anything until it calls `TaskC.requires()`

Is there any way to make this work and accomplish what I am trying to do here?

In my real-life scenario, the implementations of these tasks are much more complex, but this is the gist of how the tasks are connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great question! And Luigi actually provides the perfect solution for it and is covered here in the docs: https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tasks.html#dynamic-dependencies

Basically, you will require `TaskB` and then `yield` to new tasks in the `run` function based on the output. Let me show you in an example:

```py
class TaskC:
  def requires(self):
    return TaskB()

  def run(self):
    yield [TaskA(param=p) for p in self.input()]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of storing the output of task B in a temporary place(like Redis) and call it in TaskC. Then in TaskC, you can use "yield" to create tasks as required. Yield can be used both in requires() method as well as run() method. If you use in run() method, you have to take care of the dependencies and their failures.